# Initiate curl from https

Tags: php, curl, https, http-status-code-403, php-curl

I'm making an API connection and the server requires that the call is made from an https server, but I can't find how to initiate the CURL call using https instead of normal http.

this is my code:

```
$url = 'https://app.webinarjam.com/api/v2/webinar';
$curlHandle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Expect:"));
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept: application/json" ));
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
$query = http_build_query($data);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);

ob_start();
curl_exec($curlHandle);
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

and I just get 403 Forbidden response.

I've made sure the api key is correct as well as the url endpoint, so the only reason of the 403 is that the call is not made from an https site.

The website hosting is a shared server.

Any ideas?

Edit: This is from the API documentation:

> Please note that you’re required to connect to our server from a SSL
>   secure connection. Non SSL connections will be dropped.

Comment: Did you specify https:// in the URL?  CURL doesn't know what connection you have to the web server, nor should it really care.

Comment: The most likely problem is that you haven't preceded the URL with `https://`. Try `$url = preg_replace('/^https?:\/\//', 'https://', $url);` at the top to ensure that the URL is connecting over SSL.

Comment: the url I'm calling is https `$url = 'https://app.webinarjam.com/api/v2/webinar';`

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're mistaken on the reason for the 403.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER accepts an array as argument is so that you can specify multiple headers at once. I think this could be the problem as last one might be overriding previous ones.

```
$headers    =   [];
$headers[]  =   "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
$headers[]  =   "Except: ";
$headers[]  =   "Accept: application/json";

$url = 'https://app.webinarjam.com/api/v2/webinar';
$curlHandle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
$query = http_build_query($data);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);

ob_start();
curl_exec($curlHandle);
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```